# SharePoint 2013 Search Results shows the document title instead of the list title

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2013 Search Results shows the document title instead of the sharepoint list title.
I have followed the below steps.
1) Made the crawl mapping order of Title managed property in the below order

TermTitle
ows_Title
ows_BaseName
Title
MailSubject
Mail:5
People:PreferredName
Basic:displaytitle
Basic:10
Basic:9
EntityName
Office:2
MetadataExtractorTitle
2)run a full crawl

The above steps resolved my issue in development environment. But,in the test environment it's not working.

It's very urgent. Please help me.